# Get param value after hash in URL in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I know this is probably extremely simple, but I can't seem to figure it out or find the answer I'm looking for. I'm using Instagram's API to allow user's to login and see their feed. This is done on the client side with Javascript. After authorizing my app, the browser sends back an access token in the url like so: `www.example.com/#access_token=12345679`.

What's the simpest vanilla JS to get the raw number of the access token? I've tried `location.hash` but that returns both the key and value like so: `acess_token=123456789`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split with **'='** on the returned key value pair

```
var token = obj.split('=')[1] ;
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the hash pattern is consistent, you can get the access_token value with the following code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var accessToken = hash.split('=')[1];
```

Comment: What if the value already contains "="? Like if it's base64 encoded and has some "=" at the end.